# indexing Class objects into solr

Tags: solr, indexing

I parsed an xml file and extracted "Title", "ID" and "Text" from the file and stored them as objects. I have a collection of objects containing the info from the xml files. Now i WANT TO index these objects into solr so that I can search the relevant files.
Is there a way by which I can do that ??
Help needed.

Comment: What programming language would you like to use?

Answer (score 1):

Where are those objects of yours stored?

You can use [API](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) (java, python, ruby, js, scala, perl, PHP and even .NET) to send data to Solr directly from your source code.

Regardless of programming language, you can use standard HTTP POST to push XML, CSV,  or [JSON](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) documents to Solr. 
See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler#List_of_Request_Handlers_Available) for all update request handlers (who handles your request on Solr server) wiki pages.
And [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/request/SolrRequestHandler.html) to check out (javaDoc) which classes implement SolrRequestHandler.

If you have some kind of RESTfull service or standard web service that can return XML, you have the option to use [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to read from that source. It is then used in combination with [XPathEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor), which would avoid you having to parse your XMLs manually.

Whichever way you choose to go, first you need to prepare Solr schema.xml (add your Title, ID and Text fields) so Solr knows how to index your data.

And before all this I suggest you go through [Solr quick start tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html).